# Getting WIF to work with OpenSSO as STS

Tags: .net, wif, opensso, sts-securitytokenservice

Using OpenSSO as an identity provider, what should I do (i.e. with FedUtil.exe) to configure my .NET relying party so that it will do the STS dance?

I've gotten OpenSSO's WS-Trust client samples running, so I think OSSO's in a good state and ready for the next step.

I'm at the FedUtil.exe's "Use an existing STS" wall.  Where do I get the STS WS-Federation metadata document for OpenSSO?  I've tried:

- the.osso.server:port/opensso/sts
- the.osso.server:port/opensso/sts?wsdl
- the.osso.server:port/opensso/sts/mex
- the.osso.server:port/opensso/sts/mex?wsdl
- the.osso.server:port/opensso/sts/soap11
- the.osso.server:port/opensso/sts/soap11?wsdl

with no luck.

Thanks for your help,

Tyler

Comment: A bit more progress, but not much:

The OpenSSO federation metadata endpoint is:   http://domain:port/opensso/saml2/jsp/exportmetadata.jsp

  ...it contains an "IDPSSODescriptor" with lots of promising info.

It looks like FedUtil wants a federation metadata file with the STS details defined in a "RoleDescriptor" element instead of the IDPSSODescriptor?  

I tried using the "Federation Metadata Generator" wizard from here: (http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/2009/05/geneva-based-ws-federation-metadata-document-generation-wizard-or-oops-i-did-it-again.html)

But no luck so far...

Answer (score 0):

Since then, we abandoned OpenSSO and went with WIF and ADFS 2.0.  That being said, I've left the company and am not working on this anymore.  Here's what I can remember from back then:

- it was the stockquote sample
- I did hit some bumps along the way while following the sample instructions
- I remember there being some issue with the request URIs..  when I was testing, I was going to the wrong page
- there were also some certificate issues..   :-(

I'm sorry I couldn't remember more...  Another resource that might be helpful for you is the Apache "Stonehenge" project.  It is an open-source multi-stack/platform reference implementation of an N-Tiered system specifically designed for interoperability testing.  Here's a link to get you going:

https://cwiki.apache.org/STONEHENGE/

I wish you the best,

Tyler